# RTC - is it worth it?

Tags: arduino, timing, rtc

I need to design a circuit which will count the number of incoming impulses from an external source (the signal`s frequency goes from about 0.05 Hz to maximum 100 Hz) in a preset time interval (that can be be 20, 30, 60 or 120 seconds) and then display this number (on a LCD)

I am planning to use an Atmega mcu with the code written in arduino. My question is: is it worth it to use a external RTC or for this kind of resolution (1 sec) the internal clock is safe to use ( with milis() )?

My goal is to get something as low-cost as possible and with as few components as possible, this is why I`m considering to avoid using a RTC.

Comment: How can anyone except you judge if it's worth it?

Comment: I'm asking this because I don't know if for this kind of timing precision that I need (20 secs) there will be a noticeable difference between the two choices.

Comment: Maybe you should reword your question to ask about the accuracy of the internal clock versus an RTC, it will be less subjective that way.

Comment: I assume that the MCU runs from a crystal oscillator. In that case, they are only as accurate as the crystal, which will be measured in parts-per-million. The RTC will be no better than the MCU, assuming you write the firmware correctly. However, if the MCU runs from a ceramic resonator or an RC clock (which is sometimes internal to the MCU), then the RTC will be more accurate. Datasheets would allow you to know exactly what the accuracy would be ahead of time.

Comment: When you need to keep calendar time on a very low power level, you use RTC. Since you don't have such a condition, it would be bad desicion. Your MCU has every facility for those purposes, just waiting to be properly programmed.

Comment: Depending on which MCU you have, you should consider using 'input capture' which will measure frequency input.

Comment: It all depends on how precise you need your system to be. If you don't have to be especially precise (would 1% be OK?), then Arduino would do it.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, a real time clock is not what you want.  A real time clock is designed to give you the current time, as in year, month, day, hour, minute, second etc. It usually has a battery, so it can keep track of time when the device is switched off, and will be much more complicated than a basic timing device.  You want to measure relative time, not absolute time, so you need an oscillator.

So you have a few options:

- Use the internal oscillator in the AVR, as is. Most (all?) ATmega series chips come from the factory with an internal oscillator which is accurate to about ±10%.
- Use the internal oscillator, but calibrate it first.  You can measure the frequency of the internal oscillator, and adjust it by writing to the special variable `OSCCAL`.  You will end up with a oscillator which is stable to about ±0.3% but depends slightly on the temperature and supply voltage.
- Use an external crystal oscillator. Actually, if you are using an Arduino, there is one built into the board.  The accuracy will depend on the oscillator and how much you pay for it, but typical is 20ppm (ppm = parts per million, 0.1%=1000ppm). Expensive crystals can be a thousand times better than that.

Any of the above will give the MCU a time reference, and you then need to write some code to measure time using that reference.  `millis()` is a good start but you'll get slightly better accuracy using the AVR's built in timers.

Answer (score 0):

Real-time clocks (RTCs) are generally used where calendar and time of day are required. In your application an RTC would add the complexity of communication and software required to read it.

With a crystal-controlled device you should be able to get good stability but may need to perform some calibration to check each device you build. A low voltage signal derived from the mains (50 / 60 Hz) may suffice for your application.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f45MAo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A mains-derived reference signal.*

Answer (score 0):

Both are only as good as their oscillators are accurate.  The internal R/C oscillator of an MCU is not very good but you dont need to go so far as an RTC to make that better you can just use an external oscillator.  If you are interested in higher accuracy time get a GPS receiver.  The GPS system is designed for very accurate time, that is their problem how they solve it.  I have found an off the shelf RTC to be not very good compared to a GPS, was that strictly its oscillator?  Who knows.

You are the only one though that can define what accuracy you need, then you need to find a clock source with that accuracy.  If you dont care about time of day then an RTC is just an extra expense, use an oscillator of equal accuracy that you would have used for the RTC and just feed the MCU with it.

If you need something more accurate then a GPS based solution or there are some solutions based on cell tower signals (CDMA for example) that give the same output as a GPS.  Servers that care about time use this equipment, so it is available but often rack mounted and pricy.  Cheap GPS receivers can be had for around $10 to $15.